# ¿Cómo actualizar los hijos de un nodo en React.js?

Tags: reactjs

Hola tengo un problema para renderizar nuevos componentes en React, ya que recien lo estoy aprendiendo se me esta dificultando un poco. Tengo el siguiente componente que muestra 60 celulares.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from '../assets/Icon';
import './css/product.css';
import celulares from '../../json/celulares';

class Product extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      celulares
    }
  }
  render(){

    const product = this.state.celulares.map((el) =>{
      return (
        <div className="product" key={el.id}>
          <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${el.imagen}`} alt={el.modelo} title={el.modelo} />
          <h3>{el.modelo}</h3>
          <h4>$/. {el.precio}</h4>

          <div id="quantity">
            <button>
              <Icon iconName="fas fa-plus" iconStyle={{padding: "0"}}/>
            </button>
            
            <div id="count">{el.stock}</div>
            
            <button>
              <Icon iconName="fas fa-minus" iconStyle={{padding: "0"}}/>
            </button>
          </div>

          <button className="add-to-cart"><Icon iconName="fas fa-cart-plus" iconTitle="Añade un producto al Carrito" iconStyle={{padding: "0"}}/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Añadir al carrito</button>
        </div>
      )
    })
    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      {product}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Product;
```

El archivo celulares.json solo contiene informacion de cada titulo precio imagen y cantidad de productos. Bueno mi problema radica en que cuando todos los checkboxes esten desmarcados me debe mostrar el siguiente componente:

```js
function NotFound(props){
  return (
    <h2 id="not-found-products">{props.text}</h2>
  )
}

export default NotFound;
```

Entonces, desde el siguiente componente llamando un evento click sobre el boton `APLICAR FILTROS` intento actualizar el componente `<Product />` :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import categoryFilter from '../../js/category-filter';
import NotFound from '../assets/NotFound';

class Category extends Component{
  render(){
    const { id, textLabel, numberProducts, functionX } = this.props;   
    return(
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" id={id} />
        <label onClick={functionX} htmlFor={id}>{textLabel} ({numberProducts})</label>
      </span>
    )
  }
}

class CheckboxesFilters extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMessage: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
  const inputsCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    inputsCheckbox.forEach(input => {
      input.checked = true;
    })
  }

  checkAll(){
  const inputsCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

  if (inputsCheckbox[0].checked === true){
    for(let x=1; x<inputsCheckbox.length; x++){
      inputsCheckbox[x].checked = false;
    }
  } else {
    for(let x=1; x<inputsCheckbox.length; x++){
      inputsCheckbox[x].checked = true;
    }
  }  
}

  render(){
    const notFound = <NotFound text="Ninguna casilla a sido marcada..."/>;
    return(
      <div className="filters">
        <h4>Marcas de teléfonos</h4>
        <Category id="todos" textLabel="Todos" numberProducts="60" functionX={this.checkAll} />
        <Category id="blackberry" textLabel="BlackBerry" numberProducts="6" />
        <Category id="huawei" textLabel="Huawei" numberProducts="6" />
        <Category id="lg" textLabel="LG" numberProducts="6" />
        <Category id="motorola" textLabel="Motorola" numberProducts="6" />
        <Category id="nokia" textLabel="Nokia" numberProducts="6" />
        <Category id="samsung" textLabel="Samsung" numberProducts="6" />
        <Category id="xperia" textLabel="Sony Xperia" numberProducts="6" />
        <Category id="ericsson" textLabel="Sony Ericsson" numberProducts="1" />
        <Category id="xiaomi" textLabel="Xiaomi" numberProducts="6" />
        <Category id="zte" textLabel="ZTE" numberProducts="6" />

        <button onClick={
        () => {
          alert("xd")
        }
        }>Aplicar filtros</button>   
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CheckboxesFilters;
```

Debo aclarar que intente volver a renderizar el componente con: `ReactDOM.render(<NotFound />, document.getElementsByClassName('products')[0])` y funciona correctamente pero React me pide que no use `ReactDOM.render()` al querer actualizar un componente, entonces como lo actualizo ?

Pueden ver la app en el siguiente [enlace](https://husdady.github.io/simulador-de-compras/) , si necesito actualizar el estado de todos esos productos cuando todos los checkboxes esten desmarcados por `<h2>No se ha encontrado ningun producto</h2>`, ¿Cómo se haria?. Por lo que se, react usa el objeto `this.state` para actualizar el estado. Pero yo renderizo el componente de los productos en otro componente:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Product from './Product';
import Filters from './Filters';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <aside className="edit-products">
          <Filters />
        </aside>
        <section className="products">
          <Product />
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Entonces como actualizo el Componente `<Product />` en el DOM, cualquier ayuda o asesoramiento me seria de gran ayuda. Pueden ver los archivos de la app desde este [github](https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ReactJS, se pueden propagar propiedades del objeto `state` desde el Parent component, hacia leaf Components que consuman los mismos. Las propiedades que se pueden propagar dentro de componentes pueden ser primitivos, funciones y tambien React Elements.

En el Parent Component `App`, se puede definir una propiedad tipo bandera en el `state` object, después se crea una función handler con el método `setState`, que se encargará de modificar dicha bandera, luego se propagan estas propiedades a los componentes que las consumirán:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    //paso 1: definir bandera en state de App
    this.state = {
      displayAllProducts: true
    }
    //paso 3: configurar this de displayProducts
    this.displayProducts = this.displayProducts.bind(this);
  }
  //paso 2: crear funcion handler display
  displayProducts(value=true){
    this.setState({displayAllProducts : value});
  }

  render(){
    /**
     * paso 4: enviar la funcion handler como props a Filters
     * paso 5: enviar la bandera display como props a Product
     */
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <aside className="edit-products">
          <Filters hanldeDisplay={this.displayProducts}/>
        </aside>
        <section className="products">
          <Product displayFlag={this.state.displayAllProducts} />
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

A continuación, se pasan nuevamente las propiedades provenientes del Parent Component `App`, en los componentes `Filters` y `Product`:

```
class Filters extends Component{

      /**
       * paso 6: pasar props.hanldeDisplay a Checkboxesfilter
       */
      render(){
        return(
          <Fragment>
            <OrderAlphabetical />
            <PrizesFilters />
            <CheckboxesFilters hanldeDisplay={this.props.hanldeDisplay} />
          </Fragment>
        )
      }
    }
```

Dentro del componente `Product->render`, ya se puede usar la propiedad proveniente del Parent `App`:

```
//paso 7: validar la bandera que viene de props.displayFlag
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {(this.props.displayFlag) ? product : <NotFound text="sin resultados"/>}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
```

Nota: asegurate de agregar la ruta al componente `Notfound` dentro de `Product`.

Finalmente, en el componente `Checkboxesfilter`, antes de usar métodos de una clase, hay que configurar su valor `this`:

```
class CheckboxesFilters extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          showMessage: true
        }
        //paso 8: bind checkAll execution context
        this.checkAll = this.checkAll.bind(this);
      }
    ...demás código
```

Ya en el método `checkAll`, se puede llamar a la propiedad proveniente desde el parent `App`, el método `displayProducts`, envuelto en ´props.handleDisplay`:

```
   //paso 9: llamar a la funcion displayProducts
  //que viene desde App como props.handleDisplay
  checkAll(){
    const inputsCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

    if (inputsCheckbox[0].checked === true){
      for(let x=1; x<inputsCheckbox.length; x++){
        this.props.hanldeDisplay(false);
        inputsCheckbox[x].checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      for(let x=1; x<inputsCheckbox.length; x++){
        this.props.hanldeDisplay(true);
        inputsCheckbox[x].checked = true;
      }
    }  
  }
```

En resumen, cuando se lama a funciones como `setState`, React hace un re-render de todo el arbol de componentes y es ahí, donde se propagan los cambios de `props` y `state` hacia los componentes que los consumen. En este caso, el dueño del `state` es `App` y todos los cambios de su objeto `state` se propagan hacia los leaf components en cada re-render.

Esta solución funciona para contestar la pregunta, conforme vayas avanzando en tu investigación de React, encontrarás mejores alternativas, como por ejemplo filtrar los productos mutando un objeto tipo array desde el estado.

Comment: demore en responder ya que estuve averiguando sobre los terminos que mencionas que son nuevos para mi. Muchas gracias funciona correctamente!

Comment: Seguro, lo que me ayuda es pensar que las `props` son los argumentos y los componentes las funciones, cada componente tiene su propio objeto `state` y `props`, suerte y salud!